# Android Studio can not connect and MYSQL keep stopping due to internet connection permissions

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am new with Android Studio. My aim is really basic but it was struggled me too much. When I move my code with normal main function (with Java Sysout print method). But when the order is Android Studio, as soon as I run the code, my app suddenly stopped.

Below is my Android Studio code that you will see.

```java
package com.database.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testDB("onur");
    }
    public void testDB(String name) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.denemetext);
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.1:3306/giris_sistemi","onur","12345");
            String result = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select *from kisiler where kisi_name like '"+name+"'");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            while(rs.next()) {
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getString(1) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getInt(2) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            }
            tv.setText(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText(e.toString());
        }   }}
```

And some part of my AndroidManifest.xml file. In this file, when I establish, the internet connection's permissions, program can not start, and suddenly close.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.towntour.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you can help me my friends, ı will be verry happy with this.

Comment: Don't use JDBC from Android, use a web service to mediate between your Android app and the database. In any case, without a [mre] and the logcat/exception stacktrace, we can't really help you.

Comment: Agreed, please [do not use JDBC from a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).